# jQuery: define series of variables with .each

Tags: jquery, variables, each

I'm looking for the proper method to define a series of variables using a jQuery each function rather than a traditional javascript for-loop.

```
topic1 = $('.selector-circle').children('.selector-1').text();
topic2 = $('.selector-circle').children('.selector-2').text();
topic3 = $('.selector-circle').children('.selector-2').text();
```

Originally, I wrote script like above, but now the project requires a varying number of "topics" and corresponding text(), so I need the code to be flexible rather than the more hard-coded method I first used.

I know how to slip in a variable in a .each for the '.selector-1' part, with "i" being the each index:

```
topic1 = $('.selector-circle').children('.selector-' + i).text();
```

But I don't know how to serialize the "topic1" variable name, so that it becomes essentially "topic + i" for however many times the each runs, and then that gets tied to each respective "selector + i".

Seems like I'm maybe needing an array to be created.

Thank you, in advance, for any and all helpful pointers.

Comment: Don't do that. Use arrays, or objects, to collect multiple values in one variable.

Comment: Thanks.  That sounds right, but I'm not sure how to go about it, to create a series of values where topicX = .selectorX.text(), where X is the same for both sides of the equation and the variables are build on real values already in the HTML.  It could be 2 values for topicX or 6, so I need it to cycle through however many items there are in the HTML, and a .each function seemed right for that.

Comment: @david Can you please consider this question to be marked as resolved if your problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `wildcard` selection to select all your children. It is dynamic and you don't have to manage separate array to keep track of elements.

**HTML**

```
<div class="selector-circle">
    <p class="selector-1 someother-class">selector 1</p>
    <p class="selector-2">selector 2</p>
    <p class="selector-3">selector 3</p>
    <p class="selector-4">selector 4</p>
    <p class="selector-5">selector 5</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $selectors = $('.selector-circle').children('[class^="selector-"]');

$.each($selectors, function() {
    var title = $(this).text();

    console.log(title);
});
```

**Output**

```
selector 1

selector 2

selector 3

selector 4

selector 5
```

If in future you add `selector-6`, `selector-7` and so on, the above code will still run without need for change.

Here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upopyz72/1/).

Comment: so will the `selector-circle-1` will have multiple children? Like `selector-1`, `selector-2`, etc?

Comment: I deleted my initial comment here as it was an erroneous citation of my working code.  I think the issue I'm having implementing your solution is that there are multiple classes in the DOM elements with ".selector-1" as Peter pointed out. I'll have to return to this tomorrow. Thank you for your possible solution.

Comment: no problems.  If you get sample html of how it actually looks then may be we could help you better. Anyways Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

An array would be far much better. And depending on what you want to do with the data you may not even need to do that. You want to use jQuery `.filter()` and `.map()` methods.

```
var topics = $('.selector-circle').children().filter(function () {
    return this.className.match(/\bselector-\d+/);
}).map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
//result: ["topic1", "topic2", "topic3", ....]
```

Comment: @Subash, you're assuming that the target elements have only one class 

Comment: Yes it would, only if you use * instead of ^ but may fail if there's an element with class say my-selector-class which shouldn't match.

Comment: I don't think that is the use case in the question.

Comment: Actually, I am only trying to help you, not to discredit your answer. And I do understand that you don't have to take my suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87548/discussion-between-subash-and-peterka).

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, but, yes, there are multiple classes involved.  I tried to present the issue in it's simplest form and didn't mention that.  Thanks for the possible solution, @PeterKA. I upvoted it as it might be the one that works for me. I'm going to have to come back to this tomorrow.

Comment: **Could the downvoter kindly explain the reason for the downvote so I would take care of it?** @david, if the markup is not accurately represented by your sample code please feel free to include some sample markup.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use an array for that:

```
var arrOfData = [];
var length = 3; // change this if you need something dynamic

// fill the array
for(var i = 1 ; i <= length; i++)
{
   arrOfData.push($('.selector-circle').children('.selector-' + i).text());
}

// Heres how you fetch data
function getTitle(idx){
   return arrOfData[idx];
}
```